updating column from result of query not working in PostgreSQL
I am running this in PostgreSQL 14, in the query tool. Basically I want to create a new column testcol, and populate it with the result of another query (put the value of CITIES_BIGGER_THAN_1M in testcol if city_id is the same, otherwise leave it at null). Here is the code:
BEGIN;

ALTER TABLE cities ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS testcol INT;

WITH CITIES_BIGGER_THAN_1M AS (
    SELECT city_id, population/1000000 as pop_in_m
    FROM cities WHERE population >= 1000000
)
UPDATE cities 
SET testcol = CITIES_BIGGER_THAN_1M.pop_in_m
FROM CITIES_BIGGER_THAN_1M
WHERE cities.city_id = CITIES_BIGGER_THAN_1M.city_id;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
--OUTPUT:
-- NOTICE:  column "testcol" of relation "cities" already exists, skipping
-- COMMIT

-- Query returned successfully in 66 msec.


SELECT * FROM cities WHERE testcol != NULL
--OUTPUT: zero rows...

EDIT:
Here is the query tool I am using:

Also added BEGIN and COMMIT TRANSACTION but same result


Define 'query tool'. 2) I don't see a commit.  Add answers as text update to question text.


@AdrianKlaver question was updated

Reread my previous comment and provide the information as requested.

SELECT * FROM cities WHERE testcol != NULL  Do not use equality operators with NULL.  Try, instead:  SELECT * FROM cities WHERE testcol is not NULL

Why do you even use a CTE? It's a straight forward UPDATE of a single table and only for the records where population >= 1000000;
UPDATE cities 
SET testcol = population/1000000
WHERE population >= 1000000
RETURNING *;

